# Copy sheet from one workbook to another using NPOI in C#

Tags: c#, npoi

I need to copy a sheet from one workbook to another. I am trying with the below code, but it is not working:

```
ISheet newSheet = wb.GetSheetAt(0).CopySheet("WeeklyReport");
string filePath = "billing_template2.xlsx";
XSSFWorkbook billingWorkbook;
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    billingWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fs);
}

billingWorkbook.Add(newSheet);
```

where **wb** is the source workbook and **billingWorkbook** is my destination workbook.

**Note:** My destination workbook already had a sheet. I need to add the copied sheet after this one.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried in terms of getting the data across?

Comment: How is it not working? Nothing happens at all? Empty file, missing/corrupt data?

Comment: I am not getting any error.

Comment: If there is no error? what is the post about?

Comment: I added a breakpoint after "billingWorkbook.Add(newSheet)" and I am getting a count of 2. But when I open the workbook, I am seeing only one sheet which was already there.

Comment: I can confirm this, it seems NPOI 2.1.3.1 doesn't support copying worksheets from one workbook to another in xlsx format (XSSFWorkbook). I haven't tried the 2.2.0.0 beta.

HSSFWorksheets have a CopyTo method that accepts a different workbook as a param... It works, but it is REAAAALY slow... 6 minutes merging 3 xls files with one worksheet (each under 2 MB ) into one xls workbook with 3 worksheets...

I'm trying using Epplus for xlsx, it works but it doesn't merge cell styles to the new workbook...